# Misleading place names

Tags: knowledge, geography

> 1. an English peninsula (1, 2)
> 2. a Scottish peninsula (2, 3)
> 3. a mostly-mainland state (10, 11)
> 4. a country no longer home to lions (10)
> 5. a country never home to lions (5)
> 6. a tidal strait (4, 6)
> 7. a tidal bay (13)
> 8. a city in Missouri (3)

The answers give a final clue.

Hint/clarification:

> #1 is located in London. Apparently there are others elsewhere in England that would fit as well.

Hint #2:

> The final answer is a sovereign country.

Hint #3:

> #7 is in South America.

Comment: What are the numbers supposed to mean? Or are we supposed to figure that out ourselves?

Comment: @PotatoLatte I'm guessing the second option.

Comment: @PotatoLatte Once you have the answers, the numbers help to form the final clue.

Comment: Aren't there multiple answers for most of these?

Comment: @PotatoLatte Hmm maybe there are, although I'm aware of only one for each clue. I can try tweaking the clues if there's a specific one that's too ambiguous?

Comment: I'm sure there are A LOT of cities in Missouri :P

Comment: And I'm also sure that a lot of countries were never home to lions, and there are many scottish peninsulas, and so on...

Comment: @PotatoLatte The title is relevant :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I have so far...

> The clues refer to places that have names suggesting they are something else:
>
>  an English peninsula (1, 2) : ISLE OF ...* : IS
>  a Scottish peninsula (2, 3) : BLACK ISLE : LA
>  a mostly-mainland state (10, 11): RHODE ISLAND : ND
>  a country no longer home to lions (10) : SIERRA LEONE : N
>  a country never home to lions (5) : SINGAPORE : A
>  a tidal strait (4, 6) : EAST RIVER : TI
>  a tidal bay (13) : LAKE MARACAIBO : O
>  a city in Missouri (3) : KANSAS CITY : N
>
>  * OP indicated in comments and a hint that the intention was the Isle of Dogs in London, though fortunately it doesn't matter which one we pick.

Which makes the final clue

> ISLAND NATION

Here I am not very sure which one to pick for the final answer... Potentially

> Cape Verde, for being named after a promontory? If we're keeping with the theme, we would want an island that has a name that suggests it is not an island.

Comment: How did you get rhode island?

Comment: What about r13(Nhfgenyvn)? Because it’s a nation that’s an island but not really

Comment: You're on the right track, but there's a better fit for the final answer. Fwiw I originally had "a London peninsula" as the first clue, but changed it to be more similar to the second one. Turns out that created some unwanted ambiguity :/

Comment: ffao, I think then the first one is [your answer Dogs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isle_of_Dogs) based on the London clue

Comment: Btw, your statement starting with "if we're keeping with the theme" is spot on.

Comment: @jafe There's also Long Island, a non-nation [which was recognized by the SCOTUS as being a non-island as well...](http://mentalfloss.com/article/76297/sort-bogus-reason-long-island-isnt-considered-island)

Comment: @El-Guest That's weird. Have they voted on whether it can be legally classified as "long"? :P

Comment: Hahaha @jafe compared to other places, it’s a non-nation that’s also not long and not an island! What a time to be alive... ;p

Comment: So the bay is really a lake. Wikipedia tells me that [Bahrain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahrain) means "two seas", although I haven't read the lengthy paragraph about grammatical inconsistencies of the original Arabic.

Comment: This is the intended answer. Nice work!